# How to disallow "." (dot) as first character in regular expressions

Tags: java, regex

I want to create to regular expression that allows all combinations of characters and digits and also dots but not a dot at the beginning. So valid strings could be "1.2.3" or "1.b.34d" or something. But I want to disallow strings like "." or ".1.2.3".

I'm trying with

```
[^.]{0,1}[ a-zA-Z_\\-\\.0-9]*
```

but this doesn't work. Anyone any better idea?

Comment: Why did you add `{0,1}`?

Comment: try `[^.][ a-zA-Z_\\-\\.0-9]*`

Comment: @RohanKhude You don't need to escape the period in the character class

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use

```
s.matches("(?!\\.)[\\w\\s.-]*")
```

The pattern will match a string that does not start with a `.` due to the [**negative lookahead**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) `(?!\\.)` and contains zero or more word chars (letters, digits or underscores - `\w`), whitespaces (`\s`), `.` or `-` symbols. Note you do not need `^`/`\A`, nor `$`/`\z` since the [`String#matches()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches(java.lang.String)) method anchors the pattern by default.

**NOTE**: To make this pattern Unicode-aware, add `(?U)` (a `Pattern.UNICODE_CHARACTER_CLASS` embedded flag option) at the start of the pattern: `s.matches("(?U)(?!\\.)[\\w\\s.-]*")`.

Answer (score 2):

Use negative lookahead:

```
^(?!\\.)[\w .-]+$
```

`\w` is equivalent to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Answer (score 0):

Please try `^[^\.][ a-zA-Z_\\-\\.0-9]*`

Answer (score 0):

In regular expressions the dot character means "any character". To match for the litteral you need to escape it.

```
^[^\\.][ a-zA-Z_\\-\\.0-9]*
```

Comment: But `"[.]"` means the same as `"\\."`, so this isn't quite correct